# How to generate Checkstyle reports?

Tags: java, html, xml, checkstyle

I have a checkstyle report as xml file and want to generate a html report which lists what kind of errors occurred how many times and in which files they occurred. Something like this [example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/maven/how-do-i-generate-a-checkstyle-code-style-report-for-a-site/how-do-i-generate-a-checkstyle-code-style-report-for-a-site-03.gif).

Is there a tool to do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using mvn to do this, `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` will generate an xml format report, or with the option `-Dcheckstyle.output.format=plain` just plain text. Both of these will only list the errors and won't give any summary.

The summary html file is found in the target directory, however I found the images and the CSS are missing so it looks pretty bad.

`mvn site` will generate the HTML format report like your image. However it will also generate large amounts of other reporting material and takes a long time.

I've also found another problem - `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` will only find your config files if you include the `file://` protocol in the checkstyle plugin config, e.g.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <configuration>
      <configLocation>file://${basedir}/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

However `mvn site` only takes a directory, and can't handle the `file://`