# how can i compare check style of two java file?

Tags: java, coding-style

i want to compare two java files and after compare then ,i want check what are new check style violation has been made in new file than previous one.
is there any api which provide this service?
please help me to find a solution.
thanks in advance...

Comment: probably diff can do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is to generate a checkstyle report of particular file, and then compare it. Please look at [Checkstyle Report][1]

[1]: [How to generate Checkstyle reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342211/how-to-generate-checkstyle-reports). Once you have the report, you can easily compare the html/text file and generate the diff.

Answer (score 0):

There are many comparison tools. But i personally recommend [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) and [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) may be fulfill your desire.