# Generating Checkstyle Reports (with extended checks)

Tags: java, html, xml, ant, checkstyle

I have some own extended checks. I have exported them as plug-in and in Eclipse, they are showing warning/error. So the extended checks are working fine.

Now I want to generate a report of the violations in *HTML format*.

I have [*checked this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342211/how-to-generate-checkstyle-reports), and this works fine if no extended checks are included in *rule.xml* file. But in case of extended checks, the ant build is giving the error.

*The **error** is:*

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\Java_Work\JUnit_CheckStyle\buildCheckStyle.xml:12: Unable to create a Checker: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate InterfaceModifier
```

**InterfaceModifier** is my extended check, and it works fine in eclipse.

In build.xml, where to provide the **extendedCheck.jar** so that I get the required result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the following solution, which is working fine.

1. extract *checkstyle-x.x-all.jar*
2. copy the extended classes in the extracted directory
3. copy the *metadata,message and properties* file of extended check in the same directory.
4. if any of the file is alreasy present, then edit the file and add the content from extended checks.
5. create a new .jar file including all these.
6. in ant *build.xml `<taskdef>`*, set this *.jar as `classpath`*

Like, after done till 2nd step, I found checkstyle_packages.xml is already present, so I edit it and added the content from extended one in proper position.

---

**Previous Version**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE checkstyle-packages PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Package Names 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/packages_1_0.dtd">

<checkstyle-packages>
  <package name="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle">
    <package name="checks">
      <package name="annotation"/>
      <package name="blocks"/>
      <package name="coding"/>
      <package name="design"/>
      <package name="duplicates"/>
      <package name="header"/>
      <package name="imports"/>
      <package name="indentation"/>
      <package name="javadoc"/>
      <package name="metrics"/>
      <package name="modifier"/>
      <package name="naming"/>
      <package name="regexp"/>
      <package name="sizes"/>
      <package name="whitespace"/>
    </package>
    <package name="filters"/>
  </package>
</checkstyle-packages>
```

**Changed Version**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE checkstyle-packages PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Package Names 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/packages_1_0.dtd">

<checkstyle-packages>
  <package name="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle">
    <package name="checks">
      <package name="annotation"/>
      <package name="blocks"/>
      <package name="coding"/>
      <package name="design"/>
      <package name="duplicates"/>
      <package name="header"/>
      <package name="imports"/>
      <package name="indentation"/>
      <package name="javadoc"/>
      <package name="metrics"/>
      <package name="modifier"/>
      <package name="naming"/>
      <package name="regexp"/>
      <package name="sizes"/>
      <package name="whitespace"/>
    </package>
    <package name="filters"/>
  </package>

  <!-- Added this lines -->
  <package name="myCheck">
    <package name="checks"/>
  </package>
  <!--                  -->

</checkstyle-packages>
```

now the build file is running successfully and in the report I'm getting violation of extended checks too.