# CheckStyle generate html report

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am using CheckStyle tool for generating some reports for a java project. Also, I am using this command(extracted from a sh script)

```
java -jar ./utilJars/checkstyle-6.5-all.jar -c ./sun_checks.xml -f xml $p >> "$DEST_FOLDER/$REPORT_FILE"
```

It works fine and it generates a xml report. Now, I need also a html report. I have been looking on their site, but all that I have found is this line:

```
   Command line usage: 
-f format - specify the output format. Options are "plain" for the DefaultLogger and "xml" for the XMLLogger. Defaults to "plain".
```

I guess there must be a way to obtain a html report without parsing manually the xml report and build step by step an html file. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342211/how-to-generate-checkstyle-reports

Comment: Do you use Maven or Ant by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Checkstyle project does not have HTML report generator.
You need to generate XML and then use other tools (xslt, .....) to generate HTML.
Some xsl to process XML format (I am not sure how they works) - https://github.com/checkstyle/contribution/tree/master/xsl

Alternatively you can use checkstyle-maven-plugin - 
Here is example of hack over plugin usage 
https://github.com/checkstyle/contribution/tree/master/checkstyle-tester to get a HTML report.

To use latest Checkstyle and have active links to code lines , please read http://roman-ivanov.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-use-snapshot-checkstyle-version.html